# What is "e" variable in popular implementations of Brent root finding algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, implementation, fortran, numerical

I am reading the standard (Numerical Recipes and [GSL](http://gsl.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.6/roots_2brent_8c-source.html) C versions are identical) [implementation](http://www.netlib.org/fmm/zeroin.f)  of Brent root finding algorithm, and cannot understand the meaning of variable "e". The usage suggests that "e" is supposed to be the previous distance between the brackets. But then, why is it set to "xm" (half the distance) when we use bisection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the algorithm. However, I can compare the C source and the [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method) of the algorithm. The algorithm seems straight forward-ish (if you're familiar with methods to find roots), but the C implementation looks like a direct port of the fortran, so it's rather hard to read.

My best guess is that `e` is related to the loop conditional.

Wikipedia says (line 8 of the algorithm): 
`repeat until f(b or s) = 0 or |b − a| is small enough (convergence)`

The C source says:
 `e = b - a`, then later `if (fabs(e) <= tol ...`.

I'd hope that the purpose of the variables would be described clearly in the book, but apparently not :)

---

Ok, here you go. I found the original implementation (in algol 60) [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=6Ay2biHG-GEC&lpg=PA58&ots=D31CctBva6&dq=algol%2060%20procedure%20%20zero%20%20given%20in%20%20richard%20brent%2C%20algorithms&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=&f=false). In addition to a nice description of the algorithm, it says (starting on page 50):

> let `e` be the value of `p/q` at the step before the last one. If `|e|`< δ or`|p/q|` ≥ `1/2|e|` then do a bisection, otherwise we do either a bisection or interpolation just as in Dekker's algorithm. Thus `|e|` decreases by at least a factor of two on every second step, and when `|e|`< δ a bisection must be done. (After a bisection we take `e = m` for the next step.)

So the addition of `e` is Brent's "main modification" of Dekker's algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I can see that "e" is related to the loop conditional, because it  is read in the "if" statement... The point is, "b" and "a" in the Wikipedia conditional statement are the current best guess and the opposite point (where the function has different sign), while in GSL and Netlib codes, "b" is the best guess and "a" is the previous best guess, "c" being the opposite point.

Comment: Thanks. I could have thought about searching for the original paper via Google Books...

Comment: It was an accident :P. I wanted to learn a bit more about the algorithm. The original book just happens to be the first result when searching for "algol 60 procedure  zero  given in  richard brent, algorithms" (from one of the comments in the Fortran source).

Answer (score 0):

E is the "epsilon" variable, which is basically a measure of how close is close enough. Your particular application may not require 20 digits of precision, so epsilon lets you balance how many iterations it requires ( i.e., how long it runs ) versus how accurate you need it.

With floating point numbers you may not be able to be exact, so epsilon should be some small non-zero number. The actual value depends on your application... it's basically the largest acceptable error.

Comment: I don't think so, because "e" is a) a variable, which is changing between iterations, b) is checked only when deciding whether to do inverse quadratic interpolation or fall back to bisection, and c) there is already an "elastic" tolerance variable "tol", which responsible for what you claim "e" does. No cookie.

Comment: I think he's basically right, he's not saying it is the constant which specifies the desired precision, rather he's saying it is the value which you compare to the constant which specifies the desired precision. Matches up well with the other answer.
It could also be used to determine which algorithm(inverse quadratic vs bisection) to use based on their convergence characteristics?

Comment: e is not the epsilon variable, that variable is tol1.

Answer (score -1):

During a bisection step, the interval is exactly halved.  Thus, e, holding the current width of the interval, is halved as well.